# Write string into 1 of 10 different files without SELECT CASE?

Tags: vb.net

I have to write a string according to his calculated value into 1 of 10 files - one file for every value. The value is in the range -5 to +5, never zero.

Do you know a more efficient way then

```
SELECT CASE value
   CASE -5
     Write2File(FileNameMinus5, string)
   CASE -4
     Write2File(FileNameMinus4, string)
   CASE -3
     Write2File(FileNameMinus3, string)
   ...
   CASE +1
     Write2File(FileNamePlus1, string)
   CASE +2
     Write2File(FileNamePlus2, string)
   CASE +3
     Write2File(FileNamePlus3, string)
   ...
END SELECT
```

I think about something like

```
   Write2File(FileName%ContentOfValue%, string)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
Dim filename As String
If value < 0 Then
  filename = FileName+"Minus"+Math.Abs(value)
Else
  filename = FileName+"Plus"+value
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary to store the value to be written and the filename to be used

```
Dim mapping As Dictionary(Of Int32, String) = New Dictionary(Of Int32, String)
mapping.Add(-5, "FilenameMinus5")
mapping.Add(-4, "FilenameMinus4")
mapping.Add(-3, "FilenameMinus3")
mapping.Add(-2, "FilenameMinus2")
mapping.Add(-1, "FilenameMinus1")
mapping.Add(1, "FilenamePlus1")
mapping.Add(2, "FilenamePlus2")
mapping.Add(3, "FilenamePlus3")
mapping.Add(4, "FilenamePlus4")
mapping.Add(5, "FilenamePlus5")
```

Now to write to the file is just a matter to extract the filename from the dictionary

```
Dim newValue = -5
Dim file = mapping(newValue)
Write2File(file, stringtobewritten)
```

You can even change the Dictionary definition to store directly in the Value part the action to be performed on the data

```
Dim mapping As Dictionary(Of Int32, Action(Of String)) = 
                          New Dictionary(Of Int32, Action(Of String))

mapping.Add(-5, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenameMinus5", value))
mapping.Add(-4, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenameMinus4", value))
mapping.Add(-3, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenameMinus4", value))
mapping.Add(-2, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenameMinus4", value))
mapping.Add(-1, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenameMinus4", value))
mapping.Add(1, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenamePlus1", value))
mapping.Add(2, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenamePlus2", value))
mapping.Add(3, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenamePlus3", value))
mapping.Add(4, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenamePlus4", value))
mapping.Add(5, Sub(value) Write2File("FilenamePlus5", value))

Dim stringToBeWritten = "TestData"
Dim newValue = -5
mapping(newValue)(stringToBeWritten)
```

Comment: Nice use of Dictionary with Action!